# How to correctly use the "grep" command

Tags: unix, grep, command

I am new to linux and commands.
Basically I understand "grep" command.

But I do not understand what to do with following command, what it do, how to type command correctly.

```
grep -R -e
```

Examples to use correctly are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling grep with those flags mean search [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) in the specified directory and all it's children for lines that match a [regex](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression&ei=ZgjzUpahG6KkyQHx8oAI&usg=AFQjCNGjZ9Ib5o06o3PyyIuIlQ7E05b5pA&sig2=kLIBR0wjidIQE3CyK6qNYA&bvm=bv.60799247,d.aWc).

```
grep -R -e /p.t/ .
```

Should find all lines with a p and t that has any single character in between that are in the current directory or any of it's children.

-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern; useful to protect patterns beginning
          with -.

-R, -r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equiv-
          alent to the -d recurse option.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to type in terminal for my command?

Comment: OK, I tried "grep -R /home/pmh/ -e my_text". And I got what I want.

Comment: Great, then maybe you'll accept my answer, you can upvote to if it is valuable.

Comment: I have a file which contains many text, I would like to find the word "main" with regexp, I use your "grep -R -e /m.n/ ." but displays nothing, what is wrong?

Comment: main has two characters between m and n. it does not match /m.n/

Comment: I see that you have not accepted a single answer on any of the questions that you have asked. As a good citizen of StackOverflow if someone provides a correct answer you should accept it and you get +2 rep for doing so. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work